# For the purpose of soundproofing, do I need to comply some building code when renovate my bedroom? If yes, what it is?

Tags: sound-proofing

For the purpose of soundproofing, I wound like to add some layer inside my bedroom. 
So, I just need to drill some holes.

Do I need to comply some building code during the bedroom renovatition? If yes, what it is?

I googled building code and got this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_code), which discuss lots of building code without mentioning a word about soundproof.

I live in China.

Any ideas?

Comment: Meet the standards specified by building codes for your location.

Comment: Please let us know what your location is so we can help apply the proper codes. If you are only drilling holes, you may not need to concern yourself with codes as long as you are not drilling into structural items.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about building codes in China, and so can't really _answer_ this question. However, _in general_ (and based on my experience in the US) I would not expect soundproofing work to require any particular code compliance, or even a permit. It will, however, depend on how invasive the work is. For example, if you are touching electrical elements or modifying existing structural elements, you would certainly need to know the code for those aspects and make sure the work complies with it. If all you're doing is putting up another layer of material, probably not.

Answer (score -1):

Usually during normal day time working hours there is no problem with noise issues. However I did live in a town that if someone complained the police came and gave a warning. If you had a permit 8am-5pm was legal for normal construction.

Comment: As long as the structure is not modified you can install false walls , hang sound absorbing panels , These things are considered cosmetic . So there is no problem adding them to your structure.